# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Editing the user for a service run by a snap package

Tags: 20.04, permissions, snap, services

I installed Sonarr from the Ubuntu application center, and from what I can tell it is part of a snap package. The service cannot access a hard drive mount I am using. I set up the drive in order to be owned by a user and group I specified. Sonarr appears to be running as a system application (based on what I read) and cannot look into directories on this mount, even though I made sure I ran chmod 777 on the relevant directories. Other services I run have no issues accessing the mount or writing to it. Only Sonarr. I did alot of searching and concluded that I need to change the user that the service runs under.

This is where googling has failed me. All the solutions are years old and I could not adapt them:

1. I looked for the service configuration file in /lib/systemd and could not find it.
2. Sonarr is now installed as a snap package and does not appear to use systemd for services. I dont know what it uses. It also does not need a user to install mono first.
3. I found a snap file that appears to launch the sonarr service, but it has "DO NOT EDIT" on the first line. So I backed away.

So in order to proceed I need to know the following:

1. Are services installed by snap managed from somewhere else?
2. How can I find the configuration file for the service and change it to run as a specific user (e.g. me)
3. If I set it to run as a specific user, does that mean the user has to be logged in for the service to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snaps come with a number of limitations with regards to accessing locations outside of a user's home directory. If you're looking to have Sonarr run with very specific configuration settings, you might want to go with [the non-Snap version](https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr).

Here's the basic installation directions:

0. Open a Terminal (if one is not open already)
1. Remove the existing Sonarr snap:

   ```
   sudo snap remove sonarr
   ```

   ***Note:** Use `snap list` to list installed snaps to find the exact name for Sonarr if it's different to the one above.*
2. Add Sonarr's repository to your software sources list:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xA236C58F409091A18ACA53CBEBFF6B99D9B78493
   echo "deb http://apt.sonarr.tv/ master main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sonarr.list
   ```
3. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Install Sonarr, which is called `nzbdrone`:

   ```
   sudo apt install nzbdrone
   ```
5. Start the service:

   ```
   mono --debug /opt/NzbDrone/NzbDrone.exe
   ```

Be sure to confirm that UFW is configured to allow Sonarr access to the dedicated mount location.

Source: [Sonarr's Installation Wiki](https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr/wiki/Installation)

Comment: This worked like a charm. I added the command "mono --debug /opt/NzbDrone/NzbDrone.exe" to my startup commands and it worked like a charm. Of course this means it wont start until I log in, but its fine until they come out with a stable GUI for systemd

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help.

I was having the same issue accessing a mounted raid device on which I store all my media.

I solved the issue by opening Ubuntu Software, and Sonarr was listed under installed software.

Click on that and you should have a permissions button.

Click on that and enable both 'Enable system mount information and disk quotas' and 'Read/write files on removable storage devices'.

Last option probably not needed but I checked it anyway.

Comment: Thank You Darren.   This worked for me on 22.04

Comment: In XUbuntu it's *Snap Store* instead of *Ubuntu Software*.

Comment: I checked all sonarr options in *Snap Store* but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use snap with --devmode to use it just as a regular system package, it would have full access and run as your user. It´s what i did yesterday and i already have tons of stuff downloading.

'snap install --devmode sonarr' and enjoy life

from --help

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally yes. Snaps are supposed to be self-contained, so rarely provide services that the rest of the system can use.
2. Snaps are read-only. You cannot change files (like config files) within the Snap. Since this is an application with a web interface for configuration and account management, seems like you should be making your customization there.

   If the customization options that the Snap author provided are inadequate, then perhaps a Snap is not the best choice for you. Consider a different install option.
3. If so, file a bug report with the Snap's author.

Um, individual Snaps are usually supported by the author of that Snap instead of by us. Bugs and problems with Snaps should be reported to the Snap author instead of to us. Issues with a Snap author's configuration choices are not really a problem that we can solve.

Comment: Thanks. This was my first time installing a snap package and was not aware of their limitations

Comment: "Limitations" depends upon the use case. Most users can simply use their snaps without any configuration necessary.